# HQL with Null check for one-to-one relation

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have the following one-to-one relation in Hibernate (that could be null):

```
<one-to-one name="details" class="com.example.Details" lazy="false" cascade="all"/>
```

I am trying to select all entities that have non-null details with HQL:

```
from Entity e where e.details is not null
```

but this returns all entities, no matter whether details are null or not.

What would be a correct HQL then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok I found the solution:

```
select e from Entity e join e.details d where d is not null
```

Comment: For my case, I found that I just need this: select e from Entity e join e.details

Because it will generate a "inner join" in SQL, and it won't return results if there's no details.

Answer (score 2):

You can also most likely use the `elements` HQL function.

From the Expressions section of [HQL 3.3 Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)

```
from Cat cat where exists elements(cat.kittens)
```

Which should translate to your query as

```
Select Entity e where exists elements(e.details)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose this one-to-one relation is part of the mapping of herpderp table, hence herpderp entity has the details property.

Do you mean the query returns those herpderp records where the `herpderp.details` field is null?

Or do you mean something like this?

```
from Entity e where e.details.someDetailsField is not null
```

Comment: I mean `returns those herpderp records where the herpderp.details field is null`. Your HQL works, but the problem is that all fields inside details can be null, so I can't really rely on them. If I try to check for primary index: `e.details.id is not null`, it again returns everything (which is very odd).