# Querying the owning entity from the non-owning entity in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

I have two entities, A and B.  Entity A has the following annotations.

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="entityA", optional=true)
    public EntityB getEntityB() {
        return b;
    }
    public void setEntityB(EntityB b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
```

Entity B has the following annotations

```
@OneToOne
    public A getEntityA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setEntityA(EntityA a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
```

When I query the following, everything works fine.

```
String hql = "from EntityB eb where eb.entityA is null";
```

When I try to query with this, it doesn't work.

```
String hql = "from EntityA ea where ea.entityB is null";
```

If I follow this other [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7248991/1474991), the query works.  Why do I need to do a join to find out if the relationship is null?

Answer (score 0):

In your query you are using HQL implicit join syntax. According to Hibernate docs [15.4. Forms of join syntax](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins-forms) this form of join results in SQL inner join, which by its nature filters only those items where a match exists in the other table. Using explicit left join in hql will make your query more transparent. Turn on SQL query logging via `persistence.xml` or via your server's logging config to examine the actual SQL commands generated by hibernate.